# Why did the emoji and predictive input stop showing up on Touch Bar while typing in WhatsApp desktop Mac app on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, whatsapp.app, touch-bar

When I first began using WhatsApp Mac app on a new MacBook Pro, the emoji and predictive text were working normally whenever I was typing in the WhatsApp desktop Mac app. I could quickly access the emoji on the Touch Bar and predictive texts show up too on the Touch Bar.

But suddenly it stopped working. The emoji and predictive text stopped appearing on the Touch Bar whenever I open WhatsApp app.

What is causing this problem? Is there any way to fix it?

The issue still persists when logging in to other user accounts. And the emoji and predictive text show up on the Touch Bar normally when I use iMessage app. I tried uninstalling & installing WhatsApp app to no avail.

Comment: try joining the whatsapp beta program? or un-joining it?

Comment: @owlswipe I did that. But it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they have never worked in the desktop app. Are you sure you weren't using the browser version before? They do work in Safari.

Comment: @Algorithm_NL I'm sure it was the desktop app. It just suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but it went away after I manually went to the App Store and installed the latest version of WhatsApp desktop

Comment: This worked for me. This also applies to using `:` as a prompt to get emoji suggestions (e.g. typing `:lol` and having a little hover menu that suggests a laughing emoji), since I have an old Mac without a Touch Bar